# How to call a method in angular when an inputfield is empty?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input-field

I am now calling controller methods when this inputfield is changing :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query" ng-model-options='{ debounce: 500 }' ng-change="searchOnTags(query)"/>
```

How can I call a different method when the input field is empty again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use if statement inside your `searchOnTags` function like this:

```
$scope.searchOnTags = function(query) {
  console.log(query);
  if (!query) {
    console.log('input is empty');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `searchOnTags` function check whether the form is `$pristine`, which means the `input` field is back to its initial `state`.

When you edit a field it become dirty(`ng-dirty`), when you clear the input you can set the form to pristine state(`ng-pristine`).